# Reference for table of Schur polynomials

Tags: reference-request

Can anyone guide me to a reference where I can find a table of some Schur polynomials?  Schur polynomials of degree $m$ are indexed by partitions of $m$ and form a basis of symmetric polynomials of degree $m$. If I could find a table with even some Schur polynomials corresponding to partitions of 3,4 and perhaps 5, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a table on page 315 (Figure 7-4) of Stanley's [*Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. II*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/) expressing the first few in terms of the [monomial symmetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_symmetric_functions#Defining_individual_symmetric_functions):

[image: Schur functions]

Comment: Thank you very much!! To make sure I have this correct, is it true that $m_{21} = x_1^2x_2 + x_2x_1^2$, whilst $m_{111}=x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3x_1+x_3x_2x_1+x_1x_3x_2+x_2x_1x_3+x_3x_1x_2 = 6x_1x_2x_3$? It seems strange to me that in the second example I should need to apply these permutations even though the polynomial is symmetric already.

Comment: @Herb: the sum defining monomial symmetric functions is just a sum over orbits (the definition is in section 7.3 of Stanley), but on the other hand we might have more than $3$ variables. $m_{111}$ is the elementary symmetric function $e_3$, and in general $m_{1^k}$ is the elementary symmetric function $e_k$. Interpreted as a Schur function this corresponds to the character of the representation of $GL(V)$ given by $\Lambda^k(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these polynomials with:

- the R package [jack](https://github.com/stla/jackR)
- the Python package [jackpy](https://github.com/stla/jackpy)
- the Julia package [JackPolynomials.jl](https://github.com/stla/JackPolynomials.jl)
- the Haskell package [jackpolynomials](https://github.com/stla/jackpolynomials)

Here is an example with R:

```
library(jack)
SchurPol(n = 3, lambda = c(2, 1))
# x^(0, 2, 1) + x^(2, 0, 1) + x^(2, 1) + x^(1, 2) + 2*x^(1, 1, 1) + x^(1, 0, 2) + x^(0, 1, 2)
```

These packages are able to compute the Jack polynomials, the Schur polynomials, and the zonal polynomials.